# Is it possible to run Shark queries over Spark Streaming data?

Tags: apache-spark, shark-sql

Is it possible to run Shark queries over the data contained in the DStreams of a Spark Streaming application? (for istance inside a foreachRDD call)

Are there any specific API to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I was also looking trying to find whether this is possible. Based on the docs on the website, it doesn't look possible. If you figure something out please let me know.

Comment: The most similar thing that we could use it's Spark SQL. 
I think they are rewriting Shark using it so basically will be almost the same thing. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: But Spark SQL works over batch data. Might be they will release it over streaming data soon?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think (and it seems from the docs) that through Spark SQL you can create SchemaRDDs from existing RDDs (so also from DStreams thanks to foreachRDD() function) and run SQL-like queries on them.

Comment: Creating SqlContext and StreamingContext in the same app doesn't seem to be working. It exits as soon as i call the foreachRDD() method of JavaDStream.

Comment: That's really strange, gives you some kind of error?

Comment: Nope, just hangs there. Nothing even printed in the worker logs. I could share the code with you somewhere...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55523/discussion-between-gprivi-and-pravesh-jain).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question if someone is worried about the same problem:
the direct answer to my question is NO, you cannot run Shark directly on Spark Streaming data.

Spark SQL is currently a valid alternative, at least it was for my needs. 
It is included in Spark and doesn't require more configuration, you can have a look at it here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: I've tried and failed multiple times. Cannot figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?